# Can't sample more than 1 record

Tags: mysql, sql

Can't make a selection!

```
+----+---------+--------+------------+  
| id |    u    |    r   |      m     |  
+----+---------+--------+------------+  
|  5 |     147 |    190 | 0.00006330 |  
|  7 |     116 |    133 | 0.00002478 |  
| 11 |     116 |    131 | 0.00002385 |  
|  2 |     116 |    120 | 0.00002000 |  
|  4 |     116 |    142 | 0.00002000 |  
| 10 |     116 |    207 | 0.00001993 |  
|  8 |     138 |    239 | 0.00001497 |  
|  1 |     116 |    135 | 0.00001000 |  
|  9 |     116 |    239 | 0.00000641 |  
|  3 |     116 |    139 | 0.00000410 |  
| 12 |     147 |    375 | 0.00000052 |  
|  6 |     147 |    208 | 0.00000018 |  
+----+---------+--------+------------+
```

Tried to make a request like this:

```
SELECT `u`, SUM(`m`) AS `my` FROM `rs` WHERE `m` > 0 AND `u` != 1 ORDER BY `m` DESC;
```

But it chooses only one operation that has been performed more times, but it is necessary to count everything and display in the order in which they should be, from largest to smallest, while if there is 1 operation, so that it is not taken into.

Don't hit them very hard, don't hit them hard.

**UPD:**

Return:

> 116 | 0.00020804

Only `116`, but what happened to `147`, `138`.
How to make it right?

Comment: 1) What database are you using? 2) Could you show us the result you expect? and 3) Could you show us the result you're getting?

Comment: You are missing a group by?

Comment: @Schwern, I don't know what to do next. I am weak in this. Any thoughts on how to achieve this in a single query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the result in descending order:

**Query:**

```
SELECT `u`, SUM(`m`) AS `my` FROM `rs` WHERE `m` > 0 AND `u` != 1 
group by u
order by sum(m) desc;
```

**Output:**

| u | my |
| --- | --- |
| 116 | 0.00012906999745609937 |
| 147 | 0.00006400000179951348 |
| 138 | 0.000014969999938330147 |

Comment: 147 is more than 138, why is it higher then? |116 | 0.00012907 |138 | 0.00001497 |147 | 0.00006400|

Comment: I have added order by clauese;

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume you want the sum of all `m` for each `u`.

If you're using an aggregate function like `sum` it needs to know how to group rows together to sum them. You need a [`group by u` clause](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp). Your query should be illegal without it, but [older versions of MySQL will allow it and give you the wrong answer](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html).

The other part is you can't order by `m` if you're grouping by `u`. Presumably you want to order by `my`.

```
SELECT `u`, SUM(`m`) AS `my`
FROM `rs`
WHERE `m` > 0 AND `u` != 1
GROUP BY u
ORDER BY `my` DESC;
```

Comment: Plusanul, only the same problem, sorting is not from max to min. Worth fixing.